# Show that this limit doesn't exist

Tags: limits

How to prove that the limit does not exist for the following function

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{\sin x - x}{\sin x + \cos x}$$
I think using the definition or the sequential characterization are a way to prove that.

Comment: The first requirement for the limit of something as $x \to +\infty$ to exist is that it is defined for all sufficiently large $x$. Your function is undefined for $x = (n-1/4) \pi$ where $n$ is an integer, as denominator is $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I think you mean *for **arbitrarily** large $x.$*

Comment: @Allawonder : No, *sufficiently large* is correct. It implies “arbitrarily large”.

Comment: @MPW Oh, I just looked again and realised he said ***all** sufficiently large $x.$* In that case it does indeed imply *for arbitrarily large $x.$*

Answer (score 6):

Define $f(x)={\sin x-x\over \sin x+\cos x}$. For $x_n=2\pi n$ we have $$f(x_n)=-x_n\to -\infty$$and for $x_n=(2n+1)\pi$ we have $$f(x_n)=x_n\to \infty$$therefore the limit does not exist.